# What is "sf_max_daily_api_calls"?

Tags: heroku, salesforce

Does someone know what "sf_max_daily_api_calls" parameter in Heroku mappings does? I do not want to assume it is a daily limit for write operations per object and I cannot find an explanation.

I tried to open a ticket with Heroku, but in their support ticket form "Which application?" drop-down is required, but none of the support categories have anything to choose there from, the only option is "Please choose..."

I tried to find any reference to this field and can't - I can only see it used in Heroku's Quick Start guide, but without an explanation. I have a very busy object I'm working on, read/write, and want to understand any limitations I need to account for.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce orgs have rolling 24h limit of max daily API calls. Generally the limit is very generous in test orgs (sandboxes), 5M calls because you can make stupid mistakes there. In productions it's lower. Bit counterintuitive but protects their resources, forces you to write optimised code/integrations...

You can see your limit in Setup -> Company information. There's [a formula in documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm), roughly speaking you gain more of that limit with every user license you purchased (more for "real" internal users, less for community users), same as with data storage limits.

Also every API call is supposed to return current usage (in special tag for SOAP API, in a header in REST API) so I'm not sure why you'd have to hardcode anything...

[image: setup -> company information in a free Developer Edition, highlighting 15K limit]

[image: Sample https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php request with limits info]

If you write your operations right the limit can be very generous. No idea how that Heroku Connect works. Ideally you'd spot some "bulk api 2.0" in the documentation or try to find synchronous vs async in there.

Normal old school synchronous update via SOAP API lets you process 200 records at a time, wasting 1 API call. REST bulk API accepts csv/json/xml of up to 10K records and processes them asynchronously, you poll for "is it done yet" result... So starting job, uploading files, committing job and then only checking say once a minute can easily be 4 API calls and you can process milions of records before hitting the limit.

When all else fails, you exhausted your options, can't optimise it anymore, can't purchase more user licenses... I think they sell "packets" of more API calls limit, contact your account representative. But there are lots of things you can try before that, not the least of them being [setting up a warning when you hit say 30% threshold](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.monitor_rate_limit.htm&type=5).

Comment: thanks, @eyescream , but that's exactly why I'm confused about the "sf_max_daily_api_calls" field - the whole point of Heroku Connect is that it's not supposed to use Salesforce limits, so that field shouldn't be a reference to Salesforce's DailyApiRequests limit

Comment: It's still an API access, as far as I know it'll still consume limits. Run a sync to a sandbox and compare before/after or in classic SF UI there used to be a report about API accesses last week. I don't think you get a free pass just because SF is parent company. That's more of contract, legal area what exactly you purchased, were you misdirected. Maybe it comes with "packs" of increased limit as a bundle you purchased?

Comment: it's written in Heroku Connect's documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/writing-data-to-salesforce-with-heroku-connect#:~:text=When%20bi%2Ddirectional%20(%E2%80%9Cread%2Dwrite%E2%80%9D)%20sync%20is%20configured%2C%20Heroku%20Connect%20writes%20changes%20to%20Salesforce%20using%20SOAP%20or%20Bulk%20API.%20These%20API%20calls%20don%E2%80%99t%20count%20towards%20your%20Salesforce%20API%20limit.